RVIZ2 Dockable Panel Plugin documentation
Is there documentation anywhere on how to make a dockable panel plugin for RVIZ2? I've been having a lot of trouble trying to figure this out. The only documentation for RVIZ panels is for ROS1, and it's unclear what needs to be done differently for ROS2/RVIZ2
